# Variable Scope - access variable outside for-loop - Windows Batch

Tags: windows, shell, loops, batch-file, command-line

How can I access the variable !processid! outside the for loop?
I can't get it to work

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SETLOCAL 

FOR /F "tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('"wmic PROCESS WHERE "CommandLine LIKE '%%scanforstring%%' AND NOT CommandLine LIKE '%%WMIC%%'" get processid"') do (    
set prozessid=%%a
echo !prozessid!
)

echo !prozessid!

PAUSE
endlocal
```

Comment: do you get `echo is off` durring the execution? check also this - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266

Comment: Does it works if you replace the command with a string? Like `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ("FixString") DO (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the output from the `wmic` command includes ending lines that will overwrite the retrieved process id. You can assign the variable only when it has no value

```dos
set "prozessid="
for /f ...... do (
    if not defined prozessid (
        set "prozessid=%%a"
        echo !prozessid!
    )
)
```

Or you can filter the output of the `wmic` command to only process the correct lines

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (`
    wmic PROCESS WHERE " 
        CommandLine LIKE '%%scanforstring%%' 
        AND NOT CommandLine LIKE '%%WMIC%%'
    " get processid /value
`) do (    
    set prozessid=%%a
    echo 1 - !prozessid!
)

echo 2 - !prozessid!

PAUSE
endlocal
```

Changes made:

1 - Changed `wmic` query to use `/value` so we get an output in the format `key=value`

2 - Changed `for /f` options to use the equal sign as delimiter and retrieve only the second token in the line, so only the line with value is processed and `%%a` will hold the pid

3 - Just cosmetic, changed `for /f` to use `usebackq` and changed the quoting in the `wmic` command